# Asked to tick as answer?

Tags: support

Can we ask the post-er to tick the answer is right, if they agree it's right answer in the comment but doesn't put it as answer?

Comment: Lots of relevant threads on MSE, e.g., [Is it bad form to prompt new questioners to formally accept your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12543/246931), [Encourage users to select 'Accepted Answer' for old Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10672/246931), [Reminding new users of accept/upvote “duty”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79347/246931), [Comments saying “thank you” remind OP to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177292/246931), [Asking for someone to accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88535/246931) [duplicate]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done it before. If you are not too demanding, then asking the OP to accept an answer if he is satisfied with it shouldn't be a problem.